# Protobuf-net object reference deserialization using Dictionary: A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I'm having some issues trying to serialize/deserialize a complex object graph using protobuf-net.

I'm working on a legacy application and we're using .Net Remoting to connect a GUI client to a C# service. We are seeing poor performance with overseas users due to the serialized size of our object graphs using the default `BinaryFormatter`, which is exacerbated by the limited bandwidth in-between the client and server (1Mbit/s).

As a quick win, I thought I'd put together a proof of concept to see if there were any performance gains to be had by using protobuf-net instead, by implementing `ISerializable`. As I was testing I ran into an issue whereby object references weren't being maintained.

I've put together an example which repros the issue. I'm expecting that the object in the `Dictionary` (Items[1]) and the object B.A will be the same as I've specified  `AsReference=true` in the `ProtoMember` attribute.

Using `protobuf-net 2.0.0.619`, I'm seeing an exception thrown when deserializing (A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization).

If this isn't a supported scenario the please let me know.

Test

```
[Test]
public void AreObjectReferencesSameAfterDeserialization()
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    b.A = a;

    b.Items.Add(1, a);

    Assert.AreSame(a, b.A);
    Assert.AreSame(b.A, b.Items[1]);

    B deserializedB;

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(stream, b);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        deserializedB = Serializer.Deserialize<B>(stream);
    }

    Assert.AreSame(deserializedB.A, deserializedB.Items[1]);
}
```

Class definitions

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class A
{
}

[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class B
{
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true)]
    public A A { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2, AsReference = true)]
    public Dictionary<int, A> Items { get; set; }

    public B()
    {
        Items = new Dictionary<int, A>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like someone else had a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923891/binary-object-graph-serialization/6924039#6924039

*Standard lists and dictionaries work fine; however, I have an outstanding change request to support AsReference inside a dictionary. Meaning, Dictionary<string, Foo> won't currently run the graph code for Foo, but I can probably find a few moments to look at this if it is causing you significant pain*

It would be very helpful to me if the graph code did run for Foo :)

Comment: Just as an update: I've had a stab at getting it working in a way that requires no fussing. I have one remaining glitch to iron out, where-by currently the behaviour depends on the order in which types are discovered (which is clearly very undesirable), which I need to iron out.

Comment: Good stuff, it's nice to hear that you've been able to get something working so quickly.

Comment: The `AsReferenceDefault` optional attribute property on `ProtoContract` will be fully working from the next build

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: this should work from the next build onwards simply by marking the type's `AsReferenceDefault`:

```
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault=true)]
public class A
{
    // ...
}
```

---

At the current time this is *sort of* an unsupported scenario - at least, **via the attributes** it is unsupported; basically, the `AsReference=true` *currently* is referring to the `KeyValuePair<int,A>`, which doesn't really make sense since `KeyValuePair<int,A>` is a value-type (so this can never be treated as a reference; I've added a better message for that in my local copy).

Because `KeyValuePair<int,A>` acts (by default) as a *tuple*, there is currently nowhere to support the `AsReference` information, but that is a scenario I would like to support better, and I will be investigating this.

There was *also* a bug that meant that `AsReference` on tuples (even reference-type tuples) was getting out-of-order, but I've fixed that locally; this was where the "changed" message came from.

In theory, the work for me to do this isn't huge; the *fundamentals* already work, and oddly enough it came up separately on twitter last night too - I guess "dictionary pointing to an object" is a very common scenario. At a guess, I imagince I'll add some atribute to help describe this situation, but you can actually hack around it at the moment using a couple of different routes:

1: configure `KeyValuePair<int,A>` manually:

```
[Test]
public void ExecuteHackedViaFields()
{
    // I'm using separate models **only** to keep them clean between tests;
    // normally you would use RuntimeTypeModel.Default
    var model = TypeModel.Create();

    // configure using the fields of KeyValuePair<int,A>
    var type = model.Add(typeof(KeyValuePair<int, A>), false);
    type.Add(1, "key");
    type.AddField(2, "value").AsReference = true;

     // or just remove AsReference on Items
    model[typeof(B)][2].AsReference = false;

    Execute(model);
}
```

I don't like this much, because it exploits implementation details of `KeyValuePair<,>` (the private fields), and may not work between .NET versions. I would prefer to *replace* `KeyValuePair<,>` on the fly via a *surrogate*:

```
[Test]
public void ExecuteHackedViaSurrogate()
{
    // I'm using separate models **only** to keep them clean between tests;
    // normally you would use RuntimeTypeModel.Default
    var model = TypeModel.Create();

    // or just remove AsReference on Items
    model[typeof(B)][2].AsReference = false;

    // this is the evil bit: configure a surrogate for KeyValuePair<int,A>
    model[typeof(KeyValuePair<int, A>)].SetSurrogate(typeof(RefPair<int, A>));
    Execute(model);
}

[ProtoContract]
public struct RefPair<TKey,TValue> {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public TKey Key {get; private set;}
    [ProtoMember(2, AsReference = true)]
    public TValue Value {get; private set;}
    public RefPair(TKey key, TValue value) : this() {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
    public static implicit operator KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>
        (RefPair<TKey,TValue> val)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>(val.Key, val.Value);
    }
    public static implicit operator RefPair<TKey,TValue>
        (KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> val)
    {
        return new RefPair<TKey,TValue>(val.Key, val.Value);
    }
}
```

This configures something to use *instead of* `KeyValuePair<int,A>` (converted via the operators).

In both of these, `Execute` is just:

```
private void Execute(TypeModel model)
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    b.A = a;

    b.Items.Add(1, a);

    Assert.AreSame(a, b.A);
    Assert.AreSame(b.A, b.Items[1]);

    B deserializedB = (B)model.DeepClone(b);

    Assert.AreSame(deserializedB.A, deserializedB.Items[1]);
}
```

I do, however, want to add direct support. The good thing about both of the above is that when I get time to do that, you just have to remove the custom configuration code.

For completeness, if your code is using `Serializer.*` methods, then rather than create / configure a *new* model, you should configure the *default* model:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(...); // etc
```

`Serializer.*` is basically a short-cut to `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.*`.

Finally: you should not create a new `TypeModel` per call; that would hurt prerformance. You should create and configure one model instance, and re-use it lots. Or just use the default model.

Comment: Thanks for that Marc, a very helpful and comprehensive answer. I've gone with the surrogate approach and it's working well, however as you say, I imagine this scenario is relatively common so it would be nice to see it supported out of the box without having to configure surrogates for each KVP.

Comment: @Lee indeed; another reason to do that is that "precompile" currently *only works* with attribute-based models: it doesn't execute any code in the inspected assembly. That restricts usage on "light" frameworks (WP7/WP8/iOS/etc).

Answer (score 2):

I've setup a small test and found out that the AsReferenceDefault attribute doesn't work quite as expected.

### Test class:

```
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
public class TEST
{
    [ProtoMember(1018)]
    public List<TEST> _Items { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(1001, AsReference = true)]
    public TEST Parent;

    [ProtoMember(1003)]
    public string NameItemType;

    public void AddItem(TEST Item)
    {
        _Items.Add(Item);
        Item.Parent = this;
    }

    public TEST()
    {
    }
}
```

### Test code:

```
        TEST ci = new TEST(); ci._Items = new List<TEST>(); ci.NameItemType = "ROOT_ITEM";
        TEST ci_2 = new TEST(); ci_2._Items = new List<TEST>(); ci_2.NameItemType = "ITEM_02"; ci.AddItem(ci_2);
        TEST ci_3 = new TEST(); ci_3._Items = new List<TEST>(); ci_3.NameItemType = "ITEM_03"; ci_2.AddItem(ci_3);

        // --> Confirm references.
        bool AreEqual = false;
        if (ci == ci_2.Parent)
            AreEqual = true;
        if (ci_2 == ci_3.Parent)
            AreEqual = true;

        // --> Serialize.
        byte[] buf;
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, ci);
            buf = ms.ToArray();
        }

        // --> Deserialize.
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buf))
        {
            ci = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<TEST>(ms);
        }

        // --> Confirm references.
        ci_2 = ci._Items[0];  
        ci_3 = ci_2._Items[0];
        if (ci == ci_2.Parent)
            AreEqual = true;
        if (ci_2 == ci_3.Parent)  // HERE IS WHERE IT FAILS! 
                                  // THEY SHOULD BE EQUAL AFTER DESERIALIZATION!
            AreEqual = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for those who might come here with the similar problem:** starting from version 2.3.0 there is no need to use any tricks Marc mentioned above. Everything works as the Topic Starter wanted:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AreObjectReferencesSameAfterDeserialization()
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        b.A = a;

        b.Items.Add( 1, a );

        Assert.AreSame( a, b.A );
        Assert.AreSame( b.A, b.Items[ 1 ] );

        B deserializedB;

        var model = TypeModel.Create();

        using( var stream = new MemoryStream() )
        {
            model.Serialize( stream, b );
            stream.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
            deserializedB = (B) model.Deserialize( stream, null, typeof(B) );
        }

        Assert.AreSame( deserializedB.A, deserializedB.Items[ 1 ] );
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class A
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class B
{
    [ProtoMember( 1, AsReference = true )]
    public A A { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember( 2, AsReference = true )]
    public Dictionary<int, A> Items { get; set; }

    public B()
    {
        Items = new Dictionary<int, A>();
    }
}
```