# Stackoverflow exception in protobuf-net when serialising Class marked as AsReferenceDefault with self-referencing Dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, protobuf-net

I serialize a directional graph to file using protobuf-net.

My (simplified) classes are as follows:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Network
{
    // All of the devices on the network
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public readonly Dictionary<int, Device> Vertex;

    // The list of connections
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public readonly Dictionary<int, List<Device>> Nodes;
}

[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
public class Device
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public readonly int Id;

    // All the devices with a direct path to this node
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public readonly Dictionary<int, Device> PathTo;

    // All the devices directly reachable from this node
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public readonly Dictionary<int, Device> PathFrom;

    // the nodes that this is connected to
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public readonly int[] Nodes = new int[2];
}
```

If I try to serialise an instance of the `Network` class using protobuf-net, it will only work if he device's `PathTo` and `PathFrom` Dictionaries are empty.

Once I start populating those Dictionaries for each `Device` (which note the directions of the graph), attempting serialisation with protobuf-net causes a stackoverflow.

Does anyone know why it would be stackoverflowing?

I've read through this question: [Protobuf-net object reference deserialization using Dictionary: A reference-tracked object changed reference during deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436606), and according to Mark's edit to his answer, he fixed this graph referencing by adding the AsReferenceDefault attribute, which I use on the `Device` class.

To me, it looks like it's treating all the elements of the Dictionaries as unique individuals whilst it traverses the lists.
Considering there are ~3million devices in the network, this quickly causes a stackoverflow.

Screenshot of the debug window's stack:

[image]
([Link to full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAZpT.png))

Comment: Do you have the repeating portion of the stackoverflow stacktrace you could share?

Comment: Should that say `[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault=true)]` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell it should sorry, typo.

Comment: @KirkWoll screenshot of the debug window's stack https://i.imgur.com/uT19NK4.png

Comment: @MarcGravell just spitballing here, but when do mark an object with its unique identifier? once it's finished traversing the object's properties, or when it first encounters the object? Because if it's the former, then that would explain why there is a stackoverflow - because it is unable to mark an object as unique until it has finished traversing the dictionaries, which all loop back on one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of an optimisation I adjusted how I stored the edges, and as such I also ended up modifying my data structures so that I could remove the loops from the object references.

I created the `Edge` class to track all of the edges between the objects and the direction of the edge, and I added an `OnDeserialized` method to the `Graph` so that it will run through all the edges and re-add all of the references to each link class.

As an added bonus, this data structure is quick to save/load (for ~3,000,000 vertices, ~5,000,000 edges it takes about ~18s to load, as opposed to ~30s for the old structure), and is faster to traverse (3s for a full traverse and modify links as opposed to ~50s for the old structure).

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Graph
{
    // All of the devices on the graph
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public readonly Dictionary<int, Vertex> Vertex;

    // All of the links in the graph
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public readonly List<Edge> Links;

    [OnDeserialized]
    public void OnDeserialized() {
        // Add references to all of the links
        foreach (Edge l in Links) {
            l.Vertices[0] = this.Vertex[l.VertexIds[0]];
            l.Vertices[1] = this.Vertex[l.VertexIds[1]];
        }
    }
}

// A vertex of the graph
[ProtoContract]
public class Vertex
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public readonly int Id;

    /*
we index the edges by the ID of the other device.
It makes it easy to find specific edges and makes it trivial to only track 1 copy of an edge
    */
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public readonly Dictionary<int, Edge> Edges;
}

// An edge
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
public class Edge
{
    public readonly Vertex[] Vertices;

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public readonly int[] VertexIds;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public readonly Direction Direction;

    public Edge() {
        this.Vertices = new Vertex[2];
        this.Direction = Direction.None;
        /*
important to note that we don't set the VertexIds array in this constructor.
protobuf-net will create it for us, and if we create it here, we'll end up with a 4 length array.
        */
    }
}

/*
denotes to which index in a edge's devices array the direction the edge goes.
[Flags] so we can do checks easier:
Edge.Direction == Direction.Both implies Edge.Direction & Direction.ZeroToOne != 0
*/
[Flags]
public enum Direction {
    None = 0,
    ZeroToOne = 1,
    OneToZero = 2,
    Both = 3
}
```